# TinyTds::Error Exception: Read from the server failed (serverName)

Tags: ruby, windows, tiny-tds

Using Windows 7, Ruby version 2.2.4, tiny_tds version 1.0.0, and the targeted sql server runs in SQL Server 2012.

Code:

require 'tiny_tds'

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new dataserver:'serverName', database: 'databaseName'
```

Just an fyi, I am providing my actual serverName and databaseName in my actual code.

Running this gives the error "TinyTds::Error Exception: Read from the server failed (serverName)"

Has anyone had this issue and was able to fix it? I am assuming some issue caused by version updates of ruby and/or tiny_tds, since it was working few months back... but I am running out of ideas. 
My apologies ahead of time if some other pertinent info is left out of this question. I would be more than happy to provide any extra info as needed.

Thank you

Comment: no answers from anyone? Am I the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide all parameters for tiny_tds client depend on [git doc](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage), see the below:

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: 'mydb.host.net'
```